# Objective-C: Unicode Date Format

Tags: objective-c, unicode, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to work out how to have the UNICODE representation of 
Sun, 03 May 2009 19:58:58 -0700 as eee, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:s ZZZZ or something. I can't seem to get this working precisely.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use an [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). It lets you set a particular format string, using the format specifiers from the [Unicode spec](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns), then get the formatted date from a given NSDate object using [stringFromDate:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000447-CJBFIDDA). Also consider reading Apple's doc about [formatting dates](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1). Example:

```
// Given some NSDate *date
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"eee, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ"];
NSString *formattedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

Comment: thanks, thats it. i got it as well after debugging and going through every option. Ta

Comment: Per QA1480 you probably also want to set the locale identifier as en_US_POSIX explicitly — see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html