# How to display date as "15th November 2010" in iPhone SDK?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

HI,

I need to display date as "15th November 2010" in iPhone SDK.

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Actually, almost certainly you don't.  For displaying dates you should really be using NSDateFormatters with short, medium or long date styles.  That way, the user is in control of what the date looks like and it'll work correctly for their internationalisation settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Date Formatter as explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944085/ddg#1944111):

```
// Given some NSDate* date
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM yyyy"];
NSString* formattedDate = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
```

I believe you can simply just put "th" at the end of the dd in the format string. like this:

```
@"ddth MMM yyy
```

but I don't have my Mac in front of me to test it out. If that doesn't work you can try something like this:

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
NSString* day = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM yyyy"];
NSString* monthAndYear = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
NSString* date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@th %@", day, monthAndYear];
```

Comment: Presumably you want to use "st", "nd", or "rd" instead of "th" depending on the number (and of course this only works for English and doesn't easily localize to other languages).

Comment: you could then change the "th" to a variable and make a method that takes the day variable as a parameter and returns "th", "st", etc. set the new variable to that and we're good. However, I think that's **way** too much work for displaying a string and I would just display it as "15 November, 2010" with `@"dd MMM, yyyy"` instead. :)

Comment: Yes I agree "15 November 2010" would be fine. Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `MMMM` to get "November"? `MMM` will give you "Nov".

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm answering something old; but I did the following.

```
@implementation myClass
    + (NSString *) dayOfTheMonthToday
        {
         NSDateFormatter *DayFormatter=[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
         [DayFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd"];
         NSString *dayString = [DayFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
          //yes, I know I could combined these two lines - I just don't like all that nesting
         NSString *dayStringwithsuffix = [myClass buildRankString:[NSNumber numberWithInt:[dayString integerValue]]];

         NSLog (@"Today is the %@ day of the month", dayStringwithsuffix);
    }

+ (NSString *)buildRankString:(NSNumber *)rank
{
    NSString *suffix = nil;
    int rankInt = [rank intValue];
    int ones = rankInt % 10;
    int tens = floor(rankInt / 10);
    tens = tens % 10;
    if (tens == 1) {
        suffix = @"th";
    } else {
        switch (ones) {
            case 1 : suffix = @"st"; break;
            case 2 : suffix = @"nd"; break;
            case 3 : suffix = @"rd"; break;
            default : suffix = @"th";
        }
    }
    NSString *rankString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", rank, suffix];
    return rankString;
}
@end
```

I grabbed the previous class method from this answer: [NSNumberFormatter and 'th' 'st' 'nd' 'rd' (ordinal) number endings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312935/nsnumberformatter-and-th-st-nd-rd-ordinal-number-endings/10924230#10924230)